# Accessing Controls inside Controls in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controls

I am writing an app using Xamarin forms and I have an issue where I cannot access one of my controls so I am hoping someone can explain to me how to solve my issue.

Lets say I have 2 controls - 1 ListView & 1 Picker

```
<Picker x:Name="picker">
...
</Picker>

<ListView x:Name="listView">
...
</ListView>
```

If I want to access either of these controls from my code-behind, I can just use the names "picker" & "listView" and I find these fine.

If however the Picker is inside the ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <Picker x:Name="picker">
    ...
    </Picker>
</ListView>
```

In this scenario, I am able to see the "listView" control but I cannot see the "picker" control.

What can I do to access the Picker control when it is inside the ListView control?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The XAML you posted won't even compile.

Comment: When you place controls inside a ListView template, the control will be repeated for every item in the ListView.  There is no single instance of the control to refer to by name.

Comment: @Jason
I understand that the item would be repeated and that there would be no single instance of the control but the ListView does have an Index so you can differentiate between the pickers.

If you set this up so that the ListView had 10 Pickers, each with a set of options to choose, you would know which Picker was selected by the Index of the ListView.

I'm just trying to do a similar thing but backwards.  Essentially I want to be able to choose the Picker to manipulate by knowing its Index in the ListView.

Comment: It just doesn't work that way.  If your List has 1000 items in it, it is not going to instantiate 1000 pickers.  It is going to instantiate enough to display on the screen at any given time.  It might help if you explained what you're trying to achieve by directly accessing the pickers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by sending a reference of the "picker" as a CommandParameter.

I can then access the relevant Picker based on the Index of the ListView.